# windows Server is hacked by SOG how any one please help me?

Tags: hacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

my server is Win2K8 Web SRV , IIS-7, it is a web hosting server & my sites was hacked by someone

it is hacked by SOG say's Soldiers Of God From Pakistani Group, 
please help me to fight the situation.

how can i stop attacking from these groups.

Answer (score 4):

> please help me to fight the situation.

REeormat, reinstall. Simple like that. Reload websites from known good backups, same with database.

> how can i stop attacking from these groups.

Become competent in administeriing a windows server. Your question is similar to "I drove my car into a wall, plase help, and how can I avoid hitting a wall"

Basically - set everything up correctly, apply modern / current patches, write safe web code. It is not like there are not thousands of safe servers on this world.

Comment: actually i have installed malware bytes full PRO version and it blocks some ip addressed which is attacking on DNS, i m running this server from 2003 but this is the first time some hacking attemp on the server.

Comment: hate to say it but while its a good piece of software, especially for home use, installing malwarebytes is not at all the same thing as securing your server.

Comment: Agreed. It is actually a good aspect that tells me the advice is "Reformat, Let a professional reinstall and set up the server properly".